# pip can't resolve a dependency with an Ubuntu package

Tags: package-management, python, pip, pyqt5

I want to upgrade the package `psychopy` for Python 2:

```
$ sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade psychopy
Collecting psychopy
Collecting pillow (from psychopy)
  Using cached Pillow-5.0.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting pyqt5 (from psychopy)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5 (from psychopy) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyqt5 (from psychopy)
```

I guess `pyqt5` doesn't support installation from PyPI for Python 2 on Linux. I have the Ubuntu packages `pyqt5-dev` and `python-pyqt5` installed, but pip doesn't seem to care.

I'm running Artful.

Comment: What is wrong with `sudo apt-get install psychopy` ? You will get [1.79-1.83](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=psychopy).

Comment: @N0rbert There's a newer version available on PyPI, 1.90.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way is to get all build-dependencies with:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep psychopy
sudo apt-get install psychopy

sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev mesa-common-dev \
libglu1-mesa-dev libqt5gstreamer-dev libwebkitgtk-dev libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev \
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev \
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-dev
```

And then install it with pip:

```
sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade psychopy
```

Comment: The `build-dep` seems to have gone smoothly once I updated my `sources.list`, but pip is producing the same error as before.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: It's 17.10 Artful.